# Checking groups of checkboxes in javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I am looking for a javascript that can check multiple checkboxes within a set group.
I am searching for something that would achieve this: 
If checkbox group1 is checked checkbox 1,2,3,4,5 are checked.

I did not find a similar solution in Javascript please help me out!

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: I have a simple table with 20 checkboxes. And I would like to check and uncheck the boxes by checking a groupbox

Comment: Could you provide some of what you have done so far in your question?

Comment: I tried to use onclick="checkUncheckSome('checkboxgroup','checkbox1','checkbox2')
But this didn't work

Comment: http://gyazo.com/f5318869360cb532fb7fccfea84a6e38
This is my table, I need the top row to check and uncheck all the boxes below the given option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**here is a solution :**

**HTML :***

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="check('1');" name="GRP" id="GRP1" />G1
<br>
<input type="checkbox"  name="GRP-1" />1-G1
<input type="checkbox" name="GRP-1" />2-G1
<input type="checkbox" name="GRP-1" />3-G1
<input type="checkbox" name="GRP-1" />4-G1
<hr>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="check('2');" name="GRP"  id="GRP2"  />G2
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="GRP-2" />1-G2
<input type="checkbox" name="GRP-2" />2-G2
<input type="checkbox" name="GRP-2" />3-G2
<input type="checkbox" name="GRP-2" />4-G2
<hr>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="check('3');" name="GRP"  id="GRP3"  />G3
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="GRP-3" />1-G3
<input type="checkbox" name="GRP-3" />2-G3
<input type="checkbox" name="GRP-3" />3-G3
<input type="checkbox" name="GRP-3" />4-G3
```

***JavaScript :***

```
function check(grp_num)
{
    var checks=document.getElementsByName('GRP-'+grp_num);
        for(i=0;i<checks.length;i++){
            checks[i].checked=document.getElementById("GRP"+grp_num).checked;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is a good approach I hope! But when I try this in jsfiddle it does not seem to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: no i to had the same problem in jsfiddle copy the code and past it in an empty html file and try it on your browser it WILL work :)

Comment: I am sorry but the empty html file does not work for me either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: of course it will not work ARRGHHH i didnt copy all the js im sorry wait i'll update